# javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException glassfish 3.1 with EJB

Tags: jpa, glassfish, ejb, dao

I have create Entity,DAo and Façade in a Web app. I have no error on my codes but I am getting this exception while using find(T.class,id) method of JPA.An also it says that there is no @Entity annotation on my Entity. But this is not true.How to solve this problem.

MyEntity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "uyeler")
public class Uyeler implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "kullaniciadi")
private String kullaniciadi;

@Column(name = "sifre")
private String sifre;

@Column(name = "ad")
private String ad;

@Column(name = "soyad")
private String soyad;

@Column(name = "cinsiyet")
private String cinsiyet;

@Column(name = "ilgialanlari")
private String ilgialanlari;

@Column(name = "dogumtarihi")
private String dogumtarihi;

@Column(name = "eposta")
private String eposta;

@Column(name = "epostahaberdar")
private String epostahaberdar;

public String getKullaniciadi() {
    return kullaniciadi;
}
```

MyDaoImpl;

```
public abstract class UyelerDaoImpl<T> {

private final static String UNIT_NAME ="KutuphaneOtomasyonuEJB";

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = UNIT_NAME)    
private EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(UNIT_NAME);
private EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager(); 

public Uyeler findMemberByUserName(String username){
    return  em.find(Uyeler.class, username);
}
```

}

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="KutuphaneOtomasyonuEJB"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/MySQLConnectionPool</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>com.mesutemre.businesModel.Kitaplar</class>
    <class>com.mesutemre.businesModel.Uyeler</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/kutuphane" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Stacktrace;

```
WARNING: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UyelerDAO, method: public com.mesutemre.businesModel.Uyeler com.mesutemre.businesDAOs.UyelerDAO.findMemberByUserName(java.lang.String)
```

WARNING: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean  at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)   at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045) at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994) at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)  at 
SEVERE: Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5071)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
SEVERE:     ... 71 more
SEVERE: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity bean class: class com.mesutemre.businesModel.Uyeler, please verify that this class has been marked with the @Entity annotation.
SEVERE:     at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:648)
SEVERE:

Comment: Please add the entity and the DAO class and your `persistence.xml` to the question.

Comment: I have add my entity and dao impl.

Comment: The code looks OK. Can you also add the exception stacktrace? PS: You shouldn't use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` because the application server provides a JTA-datasource.

Comment: I have add the stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is a redeployment/caching problem with GlassFish. If you use transaction type `RESOURCE_LOCAL` and create the `EntityManager` manually and redeploy, it may be the case that the old `EntityManager` or the according factory is still cached by GlassFish and therefore only knows some old values.

**The fastest solution should be a restart of GlassFish and redeployment of the application.**

Another solution is closing the EntityManagerFactory explicitly on un/redeployment.

Anyway the preferred solution is to use transaction type `JTA` so the `EntityManager` gets managed by the container. This is a lot easier to use and less error-prone. Here is a short example:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class FileDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void store(File file) {
        em.persist(file);
    }
}
```

**See also:**

- [Persistence-unit as RESOURCE_LOCAL or JTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962525/persistence-unit-as-resource-local-or-jta)
- [persistence.xml different transaction-type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331024/persistence-xml-different-transaction-type-attributes)
- [JPA - Unknown entity bean class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159469/jpa-unknown-entity-bean-class)
- [Unknown entity class error message even though the entity is marked with @Entity annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087611/unknown-entity-class-error-message-even-though-the-entity-is-marked-with-entity)
- [Unknown entity bean class after hot deploy: netbeans 6.9 + glassfish 2.1 + eclipselink jpa 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381541/unknown-entity-bean-class-after-hot-deploy-netbeans-6-9-glassfish-2-1-eclip)